# JSON parsing, that do not have specific name for individual elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

How to get the value by parsing the following JSON

```
[
  {
    display: "Start Date",
    name: "Start_Date_vod__c"
  },
  {
    display: "End Date",
    name: "End_Date_vod__c"
  },
  {
    display: "Phase",
    name: "Phase__c"
  },
  {
    display: "Clinical Trial Name",
    name: "Name"
  },
  {
    display: "Role",
    name: "Role__c"
  }
]
```

I want to create a array of JSOn like this :
fieldLabels.push({labelName: "HCP_credentialsLabel", labelValue: results["Role__c"].display});

Comment: That JSON is invalid, in two ways: 1. The outermost layer says it's an object (`{....}`), but then it immediately contains an array without a property name. To be valid, the array would have to have a property name and colon in front of it. 2. Property names (`display`, `name`) must be in double quotes in JSON. So the first step is to have valid JSON. :-) Then you'd parse it, use the missing property name to access the array, and loop through it.

Comment: Also, you can't have structure like {[]}, because object - {} requires "key" as a string and then array, eg. {"key":[]}

Comment: But this is  the output from a library function so cannot make any changes to its structure, we need to work on this structure only

Comment: This data structure is not JSON. If you really need to read such input, you'll have to roll your own parser from scratch.

Comment: Yes i've seen in debug the actual result is like : [
  {
    display: "Start Date",
    name: "Start_Date_vod__c"
  },
  {
    display: "End Date",
    name: "End_Date_vod__c"
  },
  {
    display: "Phase",
    name: "Phase__c"
  },
  {
    display: "Clinical Trial Name",
    name: "Name"
  },
  {
    display: "Role",
    name: "Role__c"
  }
] ... not within {...}, it was i think written wrong in the library function documentation, so then how to access these array of JSOn?

Comment: @user59759: *"... then how to access these array of JSOn..."* Again, it's not JSON. The first thing to do is to stop thinking of it as JSON. :-)

Comment: Yes, i mean Array of JSOn

Comment: I suspect you're suffering from the common misconception that JSON is a synonym for JavaScript. The "seen in debug" part suggests you're inspecting regular JavaScript variables—you've even edited the question to remove some of the mistakes. JSON is a [data format with a very specific structure](http://json.org); JSON is plain text. If you are not parsing a string, it's very unlikely to be or even pretend to be JSON.

Comment: @user59759: *"...i mean Array of JSOn..."* It's not an array of JSON. It's not JSON in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 0):

You've said

> But this is the output from a library function so cannot make any changes to its structure, we need to work on this structure only

Well, the library function is not producing JSON. If the structure is reliably in the form you describe, you could just remove the leading `{` and trailing `}`, wrap it in `()`, and pass it through `eval`, but **never use `eval` on untrusted data** as it allows arbitrary code execution.

**If you trust the source of the data**, then it's fairly easy:

```
var str = /*...your data string...*/;
// Remove the first { and last }, wrap in ()
str = "(" + str.trim().replace(/(?:^{)|(?:}$)/g, "") + ")";
// Parse it -- DO NOT USE eval ON UNTRUSTED DATA
var array = eval(str);
```

Live Example:

```js
var str = '{' +
'[' +
'  {' +
'    display: "Start Date",' +
'    name: "Start_Date_vod__c"' +
'  },' +
'  {' +
'    display: "End Date",' +
'    name: "End_Date_vod__c"' +
'  },' +
'  {' +
'    display: "Phase",' +
'    name: "Phase__c"' +
'  },' +
'  {' +
'    display: "Clinical Trial Name",' +
'    name: "Name"' +
'  },' +
'  {' +
'    display: "Role",' +
'    name: "Role__c"' +
'  }' +
']}';

str = "(" + str.trim().replace(/(?:^{)|(?:}$)/g, "") + ")";
var array = eval(str);
// Then use the array, for instance
array.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry.display);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

That's not valid JSON, because the array doesn't have a key. This should fix it:

> `{
>   arr: [
>   ...
>   ]
>   }`

Then you can access each individual element by its index. E.g. obj.arr[0].display